# Returning to the start of a while loop mid-loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, while-loop, continue

I'm doing a last assessment for the semester and interestingly enough, the code I have written seems to be devoid of errors other than a few simple ones I have just ironed out. However, I am stuck with one last error I cannot get my head around.

The program I am doing is a random numbers generator, using a while loop to generate the numbers and store them in the array, however, a second while loop has to be used to check to see if that number is already in the array, if that number is already in the array, this number has to be discarded and another value has to be obtained to put into the same index. After this the array is printed as a grid of 5x 10. However, upon using a continue command towards the end of the first loop, it comes up with the error:

```
Random50.java:52: error: continue outside of loop
continue;
^
```

As much as it seems obvious, I have no idea how to alter my code to make the program run, I was using the the continue command to return to the start of the first loop without incrementing a counter variable, so another value could be stored in the same index again.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Random50
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    // Declare and initalise array
    int[] random50 = new int[5];

    // Declare and initalise counter variable

    int i = 0;

    // Declare and initalise repeater variable

    int r = 0;

    // Generator while loop
    while (i < random50.length)
    {
        // Generate random number
        int n = (int) (Math.random() * 999) + 1;
        // Initalise variables for second while loop
        int searchValue = i;
        int position = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        // Duplicate while loop
        while (position < random50.length && !found)
        {
            if (random50[position] == searchValue)
            {
                found = true;
            }

            else
            {
                position++;
            }

        }

        // Return to first loop, determine if duplicate to return to the start of the loop early
        if (found);
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Store value into array
        random50[i] = n;

        // Print value and add to counter variable
        System.out.print(random50[i] + " ");
        r++;
        // reset counter variable to maintain grid
        if (r == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            r = 0;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

}

So, how can I get the continue to work or in other words, return to the start of the first loop mid loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `while()` loop terminating instantly due to an obsolete `;` probably placed by accident:

```
while (i < random50.length);
```

So your whole loop body will execute exactly once, no matter the condition (which will most likely be optimized out).

Once this is fixed, your use of `continue;` should work as expected.

**Edit:**

Same problem further down below:

```
if (found);
```

Due to this line you'll always execute the `continue;` following within these brackets, so the code below becomes unreachable.

Comment: The continue in no longer an error, now I'm getting an compile error when I am storing the value into the array ie random50[i] = n; the value being unreachable